# Is it legal to instantiate a class which has no explicit constructor?

Tags: php

I recently created two code examples to test how constructors work in php, one with an explicit constructor and other without. Both output was the same.

Is it legal to instantiate a class which has no explicit constructor?

Code with constructor

```
<?php
class Circle {
      const PI = 3.14;
      public $radius;

//Constructor method 
       public function __construct($r) {
             $this->radius = $r;
       }

       public function calculate() {
             return 2 * self::PI * $this->radius;
       }
}

//Argument passed during instantiating
 $C = new Circle(7);
 echo ("Circumference of Circle: ".$C->calculate());
?>
```

Code without Constructor

```
 <?php
   class Circle {
        const PI = 3.14;
        public $radius;

    //Non-ideal class mutation method 
            public function calculate($r) {
                $this->radius = $r;
                return 2 * self::PI * $this->radius;
            }
        }

     $C = new Circle();
    //Argument was passed directly to the method
    echo ("Circumference of Circle: ".$C->calculate(7));
 ?>
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Copy paste the code, select it, and press the `{ }` icon in the toolbar of the edit box.

Comment: Ok sorry I was asking using mobile app

Comment: Absolutely nothing wrong with a class without an explicit default ctor, as you said, one generally gets created by the compiler anyway.  And it's perfectly legitimate to have a class that doesn't need one, there's certainly no law against it.  The one without a parameter in the ctor could be seen as a "Logic Engine", whereas the one with a parameter could be seen as an "Object with Properties".

Comment: Very much appreciate @DanRayson for your knowledge. Thank you

Comment: Also, side-note: PHP has a built-in constant [`M_PI`](http://php.net/manual/en/math.constants.php) so you don't need to define it yourself.

Comment: The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) is also implying that it is optional: *PHP 5 **allows** developers to declare constructor methods for classes. Classes which have a constructor method call this method on each newly-created object.*

Comment: Thank you all for your constructive answers. You really have saved me...

Comment: I downvoted the question and voted to close as unclear, since the OP was asked hours ago to post real code instead of images of it and failed to update the question.

Comment: Ok then I will edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a constructor method is optional. The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) states:

> PHP 5 **allows** developers to declare constructor methods for classes. Classes which have a constructor method call this method on each newly-created object.

Note however that your second implementation is not ideal:

- the `calculate` method has a side-effect: it sets the *radius* member. This is not best practice: if a method's main purpose is to return something, then it should not mutate the object.
- the `calculate` method requires you to provide the radius *on every call*. This is not really what you want when the object is supposed to *know* its radius.